# Problem In UISplitViewController in iPad

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on UISplitView Controller. I have used a SplitView controller template of Xcode. Actually i wanted to implement a scenraio in which when i click on table view cell it should add a New Root Controller with a table View into the Navigation Stack.

i did it using the following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:YES];
[nextView release];
}
```

It works perfect and i have used the RootView Controller code into the NextViewController so that when we click on New Screen's cell it should update my Detail Screen. But unfortuantely it is not updating my Detail Screen.

What can be the reason ??

Please help friends..

Thanks

Comment: is there any one who can help ??

Answer (score 0):

To updating your Detail Screen. you need to implement a delegate method of communication between Current RootView controller and Detailview controller.

Best Wishes,